# Override Storyboard Configurations in Xcode with Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to have the height of my `UITableView` cells depend on the material they contain. My view controller object is a subclass of `UITableViewController` and conforms to the `<UITableViewDelegate>` protocol. Is this the correct place to reference the protocol?

Then in my implementation I declare

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [indexPath row] * 20;
}
```

but when I run the app each row is of fixed height that is visually represented in the storyboard. Is it something with the prototype cell that is overriding my code? Am I missing something completely naive?

Comment: Is the heightForRowAtIndexPath method being called? what you are returning doesn't seem like it would return a float, just the row's index multiplied by 20, is that really the height you are seeking?

Comment: That's not the way I'd actually like it implemented, but it should show rows of varying height to let me know it's working.

Comment: Ok, but is it being called? If you add a log, is it printed?

Comment: I added a log and nothing printed. I haven't been doing this for very long- I thought these methods that I was "overriding" were being called elsewhere. How do i manually do it?

Comment: Like the answer posted below, have you made sure that you are actually the tableview's delegate in this subclass?

Comment: No - I can't use the storyboard to drag the connection into the implementation (Xcode won't allow it). Is this to be done in the ViewController? Do I need to declare the property delegate somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your view controller as delegate to table view. You can do it either through connection inspector of your table view in xib/ storyboard. Or you can do it by doing following in your initWithNibName:bundle: method

```
myTableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: When I try to use Xcode to 'pull' the connection of delegate it won't allow it into the file. Now it reads `delegate - Table View` under referencing outlets. Is this connection in the controller or somewhere else?

Comment: If it reads delegate - table view, connection has been setup. Did you setup data source? Data source is used to provide data to be displayed in table.